# Weblogic Deployment Failing

Tags: oracle, weblogic, weblogic-10.x, weblogic11g, weblogic12c

I am trying to deploy my `.ear` file to a `weblogic` server and I am getting an issue with deploying the files...Here is the stack trace and errors - I am deploying using the admin console

```
Message icon - Error Unable to access the selected application.
Message icon - Error Exception in AppMerge flows' progression
Message icon - Error Exception in AppMerge flows' progression

Message icon - Error [J2EE:160161]Error while parsing the Application descriptors for jwds0002.ear: weblogic.descriptor.DescriptorException: Unmarshaller failed at weblogic.descriptor.internal.MarshallerFactory$1.createDescriptor(MarshallerFactory.java:152) at 
weblogic.descriptor.BasicDescriptorManager.createDescriptor(BasicDescriptorManager.java:306) at weblogic.application.descriptor.AbstractDescriptorLoader2.getDescriptorBeanFromReader(AbstractDescriptorLoader2.java:788) at weblogic.application.descriptor.AbstractDescriptorLoader2.createDescriptorBean(AbstractDescriptorLoader2.java:409) at weblogic.application.descriptor.AbstractDescriptorLoader2.loadDescriptorBeanWithoutPlan(AbstractDescriptorLoader2.java:759) at weblogic.application.descriptor.AbstractDescriptorLoader2.loadDescriptorBean(AbstractDescriptorLoader2.java:768) at weblogic.application.ApplicationDescriptor.getWeblogicApplicationDescriptor(ApplicationDescriptor.java:339) at weblogic.application.compiler.CompilerCtx.setApplicationDescriptor(CompilerCtx.java:139) at weblogic.application.compiler.AppcUtils.setDDs(AppcUtils.java:142) at weblogic.application.compiler.flow.DescriptorParsingFlow.compile(DescriptorParsingFlow.java:57) at weblogic.application.compiler.FlowDriver$FlowStateChange.next(FlowDriver.java:69) at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:37) at weblogic.application.compiler.FlowDriver.nextState(FlowDriver.java:36) at weblogic.application.compiler.FlowDriver$CompilerFlowDriver.compile(FlowDriver.java:96) at weblogic.application.compiler.ReadOnlyEarMerger.merge(ReadOnlyEarMerger.java:49) at weblogic.application.compiler.flow.AppMergerFlow.mergeInput(AppMergerFlow.java:94) at weblogic.application.compiler.flow.AppMergerFlow.compile(AppMergerFlow.java:47) at weblogic.application.compiler.FlowDriver$FlowStateChange.next(FlowDriver.java:69) at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:37) at weblogic.application.compiler.FlowDriver.nextState(FlowDriver.java:36) at weblogic.application.compiler.FlowDriver$CompilerFlowDriver.compile(FlowDriver.java:96) at weblogic.application.compiler.AppMerge.runBody(AppMerge.java:157) at weblogic.utils.compiler.Tool.run(Tool.java:158) at weblogic.utils.compiler.Tool.run(Tool.java:115) at weblogic.application.compiler.AppMerge.merge(AppMerge.java:169) at weblogic.deploy.api.internal.utils.AppMerger.merge(AppMerger.java:88) at weblogic.deploy.api.internal.utils.AppMerger.getMergedApp(AppMerger.java:63) at weblogic.deploy.api.model.internal.WebLogicDeployableObjectFactoryImpl.createDeployableObject(WebLogicDeployableObjectFactoryImpl.java:181) at weblogic.deploy.api.model.internal.WebLogicDeployableObjectFactoryImpl.createLazyDeployableObject(WebLogicDeployableObjectFactoryImpl.java:156) at weblogic.deploy.api.tools.SessionHelper.inspect(SessionHelper.java:661) at com.bea.console.actions.app.install.Flow$2.execute(Flow.java:463) at com.bea.console.utils.DeploymentUtils.runDeploymentAction(DeploymentUtils.java:4700) at com.bea.console.actions.app.install.Flow.appSelected(Flow.java:461) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.FlowController.invokeActionMethod(FlowController.java:870) at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.FlowController.getActionMethodForward(FlowController.java:809) at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.FlowController.internalExecute(FlowController.java:478) at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowController.internalExecute(PageFlowController.java:306) at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.FlowController.execute(FlowController.java:336) at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.internal.FlowControllerAction.execute(FlowControllerAction.java:52) at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:431) at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowRequestProcessor.access$201(PageFlowRequestProcessor.java:97) at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowRequestProcessor$ActionRunner.execute(PageFlowRequestProcessor.java:2044) at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.interceptor.action.internal.ActionInterceptors$WrapActionInterceptorChain.continueChain(ActionInterceptors.java:64) at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.interceptor.action.ActionInterceptor.wrapAction(ActionInterceptor.java:184) at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.interceptor.action.internal.ActionInterceptors$WrapActionInterceptorChain.invoke(ActionInterceptors.java:50) at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.interceptor.action.internal.ActionInterceptors$WrapActionInterceptorChain.continueChain(ActionInterceptors.java:58) at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.interceptor.action.internal.ActionInterceptors.wrapAction(ActionInterceptors.java:87) at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowRequestProcessor.processActionPerform(PageFlowRequestProcessor.java:2116) at com.bea.console.internal.ConsolePageFlowRequestProcessor.processActionPerform(ConsolePageFlowRequestProcessor.java:255) at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:236) at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowRequestProcessor.processInternal(PageFlowRequestProcessor.java:556) at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowRequestProcessor.process(PageFlowRequestProcessor.java:853) at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.AutoRegisterActionServlet.process(AutoRegisterActionServlet.java:631) at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowActionServlet.process(PageFlowActionServlet.java:158) at com.bea.console.internal.ConsoleActionServlet.process(ConsoleActionServlet.java:256) at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:414) at com.bea.console.internal.ConsoleActionServlet.doGet(ConsoleActionServlet.java:133) at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowUtils.strutsLookup(PageFlowUtils.java:1199) at com.bea.portlet.adapter.scopedcontent.ScopedContentCommonSupport.executeAction(ScopedContentCommonSupport.java:686) at com.bea.portlet.adapter.scopedcontent.ScopedContentCommonSupport.processActionInternal(ScopedContentCommonSupport.java:142) at com.bea.portlet.adapter.scopedcontent.PageFlowStubImpl.processAction(PageFlowStubImpl.java:106) at com.bea.portlet.adapter.NetuiActionHandler.raiseScopedAction(NetuiActionHandler.java:111) at com.bea.netuix.servlets.controls.content.NetuiContent.raiseScopedAction(NetuiContent.java:181) at com.bea.netuix.servlets.controls.content.NetuiContent.raiseScopedAction(NetuiContent.java:167) at com.bea.netuix.servlets.controls.content.NetuiContent.handlePostbackData(NetuiContent.java:225) at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlLifecycle$2.visit(ControlLifecycle.java:180) at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:324) at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334) at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334) at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334) at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334) at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334) at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334) at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334) at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334) at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334) at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334) at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334) at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334) at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334) at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334) at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334) at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334) at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334) at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334) at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334) at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334) at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334) at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334) at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walk(ControlTreeWalker.java:130) at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.processLifecycles(Lifecycle.java:395) at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.processLifecycles(Lifecycle.java:361) at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.processLifecycles(Lifecycle.java:352) at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.runInbound(Lifecycle.java:184) at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.run(Lifecycle.java:159) at com.bea.netuix.servlets.manager.UIServlet.runLifecycle(UIServlet.java:388) at com.bea.netuix.servlets.manager.UIServlet.doPost(UIServlet.java:258) at com.bea.netuix.servlets.manager.UIServlet.service(UIServlet.java:199) at com.bea.netuix.servlets.manager.SingleFileServlet.service(SingleFileServlet.java:251) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820) at com.bea.console.utils.MBeanUtilsInitSingleFileServlet.service(MBeanUtilsInitSingleFileServlet.java:54) at weblogic.servlet.AsyncInitServlet.service(AsyncInitServlet.java:130) at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227) at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125) at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:292) at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26) at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:42) at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27) at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:42) at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3496) at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321) at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(Unknown Source) at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2180) at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2086) at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1406) at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:201) at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:173) Caused by: com.bea.xml.XmlException: failed to load java type corresponding to e=weblogic-application@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application at com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.UnmarshalResult.getPojoBindingType(UnmarshalResult.java:361) at com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.UnmarshalResult.determineTypeForGlobalElement(UnmarshalResult.java:316) at com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.UnmarshalResult.determineTypeForGlobalElement(UnmarshalResult.java:326) at com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.UnmarshalResult.determineRootType(UnmarshalResult.java:307) at com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.UnmarshalResult.unmarshalDocument(UnmarshalResult.java:158) at com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:65) at weblogic.descriptor.internal.MarshallerFactory$1.createDescriptor(MarshallerFactory.java:141) ... 120 more .
```

**Application XML File:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.4">
<display-name>jwds0002.ear</display-name>
<module>
    <web>
        <web-uri>jwds0002.war</web-uri>
        <context-root>jwds0002</context-root>
    </web>
</module>
</application>
```

**Also another question:** I  have a test server installed locally that is running Oracle Weblogic 11g and it deploys just fine - however, prod environment is on 10g - is this a big deal? I wonder if weblogic versions is actually the problem?

Comment: Can you post your `application.xml` file?

Comment: added the `application.xml` file

Comment: The namespace of XML descriptor(s) may point to incorrect WLS version. Do you have a weblogic.xml? (inside of jwds0002.war file)

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs either because your project is structured incorrectly else because your deployment descriptor is incorrect/weblogic incompatible.
Check your web.xml - the most probable cause.